# Extracting Values from Wordpress Get_Post_Meta

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, variables

I am using `get_post_meta($post->ID);`, which returns results like the below.

I need to print to the screen the actual values for these fields wpcf-business_listing_title, wpcf-street_address, wpcf-city, etc.

How exactly do I do that?  Thank you!

```
array(25) { 
    ["wpcf-business_listing_title"]=> array(1) {
         [0]=> string(17) "Davis Car Dealer" 
     } 
    ["wpcf-street_address"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(21) "720 Olympad Drive Ste X" 
     } 
    ["wpcf-city"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(5) "Portland" 
     } 
    ["wpcf-state_abbreviation"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(2) "ME" 
     } 
    ["wpcf-full_state_name"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(10) "Maine" 
     } 
    ["wpcf-zip_code"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(5) "95616" 
     } 
    ["wpcf-county"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(4) "Yolo" 
    } 
    ["wpcf-phone_number"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(12) "555-755-3666" 
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) where each item contains a flat array with custom field values. I suggest you read up on [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [looping](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) in PHP. For the record associative array elements are accessed using the bracket notation eg. *$meta['my-assoc-key']*

Answer (score 1):

Here You can give the particular field slug name for example you using for wpcf-street_address then you want give like

`$wpcf-street_address = get_post_meta($post->ID,'wpcf-street_address',true);`

this gives you particular field value.

Comment: does this run a query when I do get_post_meta?  Is there any way to do it without running a query?  I am trying to limit my queries because on each record listed on the page I need to do get_post_meta for several different custom fields.